# What would be the best self preservation time parameter configuration for Eureka server for 12 Microservices and 2 instance for each Microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am having 12 Microservices including 1 Eureka server and 1 API Gateway deployed on AWS ( Kubernetes + Docker images ), but I am facing issue of frequently getting register deregister issue with Microservices, the Microservices count 12 is not constant on Eureka Server Dashboard, sometime shows 10, sometime 7 and again 12 after every time on page refresh.

And because of this behavior I am getting **Forwarding Error** at API gateway, cause by **Load Balancer Does not available for the Client....**

Also on Eureka server dashboard it show below Error

**EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.**

I am having below configuration for self preservation and it looks like something is wrong with that, Could you please help me to fix this issue.

```
eureka.server.eviction-internal-timer-in-ms=15000
eureka.instane.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=30
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=90
eureka.renewalPercentThreshold=0.85
```

Also using Some **hystrix** properties  as below -

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=30000000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=3000000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=1000000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

In the K8s environment, instances are not deleted after self-protection is enabled. As a result, some requests are connected to non-existent instances

Can try to disable it:
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=false

Comment: If we disable self-preservation mode, then we will miss heartbeats from Eureka instances to re-register instances in case of any network issue in AWS or MS getting down etc.